# how to take input int with % in c?

Tags: c

I have to take two inputs from the user with %
input example: 20% 30%
I tried this
`scanf("%d%d ", &x,&y);`

how can I input two values with %? I can only take two integer values.

Comment: A very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143906/why-two-int-input-a-2-b-4-outputs-2-and-0) was deleted an hour ago. You'll need to filter the input.

Comment: `scanf()` will not recognize a `%` character in the input as part of the number.  In order for `scanf()` to consume it, then, there needs to be a matching directive in your format.  There are several alternatives, but the simplest and most specific would be `%%` to match one `%` character (and nothing else).

Answer (score 2):

`%%` matches literal % character, so this should do it:

```
int r = scanf("%d%%%d%%", &x,&y); 
if(r != 2) { 
    puts("scanf error");
    exit(1);
}
```

General note: it's more robust to read entire lines with `fgets` or POSIX `getline`, then parse them, for example with `sscanf`.

Also, please read `scanf` documentation on what `%d` and `%%` do, and what the return value actually means.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you really obligated to also take the %? Couldn't you instead ask the user to input integers?

If you still want to take inputs with %, I think you could treat your inputs as char*, iterate through them until you encounter the '%' char, and then delete it.
You could then use the atoi function to transform your char* into integers.